# Proof that sequence converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation

How can I prove that $ (a_n) = \frac{n^3 -1}{2n^3-n} $ converges?

I've calculated the limit and got a result of a 1/2.

Now I need to prove that this limit exists. So, I tried to use the definition and find an $M$ that $n > M \implies |a_n - L| < \epsilon$ for $ \epsilon > 0 $, but I couldn't reach in a result.

Is there any strategy to prove that this sequence converges?

Comment: Are you required to use the $\varepsilon-M$ definition of sequential convergence? (Well, usually called $\varepsilon-N$ but you're using $M$ so same difference.)

Comment: No it's not a requirement to use that definition. On other exercises, I used that definition and I could proof the convergence. But in this one, I couldn't see another way to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** You can use the sandwich theorem here as an alternative. Note that
$$\frac{n^3-1}{2n^3}\leq\frac{n^3-1}{2n^3-n}\leq\frac{n^3}{2n^3-n}$$
Now, $\frac{n^3-1}{2n^3}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2n^3}$ and you can use the result that **if $a_n$ converges to a and $b_n$ converges to b, then $a_n+b_n$ converges to a+b** to find it's limit.

For the $\frac{n^3}{2n^3-n}$, you can use the $\epsilon-N$ definition of convergence.

> Choose any $\epsilon>0$ and thus, $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$, such that $N>\sqrt{\frac{1}{4\epsilon}+\frac{1}{2}}$ by the Archimedean property.

Can you do the rest?

Comment: Oh, thanks for showing me this nice way to proof. I couldn't manipulate the sequence to fit in sandwich theorem, it showed me new horizons!

Comment: @MatheusDaCostaConceição That's totally fine...

Answer (score 1):

For all $\epsilon > 0$, by the Archimedean Property, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $N >  \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{\epsilon + \frac{1}{2}}}$, then for all $n \geq N$, we have $\frac{1}{n^3} < \epsilon + \frac{1}{2}$ and

\begin{align*}
\left| a_n - \frac{1}{2} \right| &= \left| \frac{n^3 - 1}{2n^3 - n} - \frac{1}{2} \right|\\
&= \left| \frac{1 - \frac{1}{n^3}}{2 - \frac{1}{n^2}} - \frac{1}{2} \right|\\
&\leq \left| 1 - \frac{1}{n^3} - \frac{1}{2} \right| \hspace{20pt} \mbox{(since $2 - \frac{1}{n^2} \geq 1$})\\
&= \left| \frac{1}{n^3} - \frac{1}{2} \right| \\
&< \epsilon
\end{align*}

Comment: Wow, that manipulation made at 3rd line was the trigger to understand how to use the definition. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

If you have proved the algebraic limit laws for sequences, then this isn't too bad. $$\begin{align*}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^3-1}{2n^3-n}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-\frac{1}{n^3}}{2-\frac{1}{n^2}}\\&=\frac{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1-\frac{1}{n^3})}{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(2-\frac{1}{n^2})}\\&=\frac{1}{2}\end{align*}$$ This works because both the top and bottom limits exist and the bottom limit is non-zero for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Understood! I can use the algebraic limit laws for sequences to proof in that way. It is a clean way to prove. Thanks!!